# How to execute stored procedure in SQL Server from C# chatbot with bot application?

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is the SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_nearest_Restaurants
    @lat FLOAT,
    @lng FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @point GEOMETRY

    SET @point = GEOMETRY::Point(@lat, @lng, 4326)

    SELECT TOP (5) 
        Id, Name, City, @point.STDistance(Location) AS Location 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Restaurants]
    ORDER BY 
        @point.STDistance(Location)
END
GO
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about what you're trying to do?  Do you have a server application which connects to a database and you want to know how to trigger the SP from a client application, or do you just want to know how to run an SP from code?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin  i use microsoft bot emulator on a localhost and i try to implement stored procedure with sql server as the example that i have post

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin also the name of my function is this "public async Task MessageReceivedNearestMuseums(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SqlCommand` to refer to your `StoredProcedure`, then fetch data with `SqlDataAdapter`.

Don't forget to pass the parameters by `SqlParameter`.

This code will call your sp (`get_nearest_Restaurants`)in you BotApplication:

```
public async Task<DataTable> ExecuteSp(string lat, string lng)
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName/IP;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("get_nearest_Restaurants", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lat", lat));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lng", lng));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        await Task.FromResult(da.Fill(dt)); 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

To Connect to `SQL-Server` you should use `SqlConnection`.
There is a property in `SqlConnection`, which is `ConnectionString`, which define where is our `SQL-Server` and how can we connect to it.

Comment: thank you for your support and appreciate but my function in bot app starts with  public async Task MessageReceivedNearestMuseums(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)  for passing a messages  so how can i implement with this function?   @Siavash

Comment: Thank you, I updated the method to an async method signature. Now you can call this method in your bot app which is async as well. and I highly suggest you to put your code (bot app) here if you want to get better response. @takilass

Comment: also with catch (Exception x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Exception Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }  in bot app is different the structure how can i write that? one example of my previous function how the message print into the emulator is this::      await context.PostAsync("message"); @Siavash

Comment: I forgot to remove MessageBox lines of code, I updated my answer.